# Fundamental period of $e^{ik_1x}+e^{ik_2x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Is the function $f(x)=e^{ik_1x}+e^{ik_2x}$ periodic? Clearly, the first term is $T_1=2\pi/k_1$-periodic and the second is $T_2=2\pi/k_2$-periodic. Can I say something about $f$?. 
I read that if $T_1/T_2\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $f$ is, but what is its fundamental period?

Comment: Consider the simplest case: What if $T_1,T_2$ are both integers? Do you know the answer then?

Comment: In that case $T_1/T_2$ is rational, so $f$ is periodic. But I dont know the fundamental period.

Comment: Let's make it even simpler, then. What if $T_1=2,T_2=3$? What is the fundamental period then? What if $T_1=2,T_2=4$? After looking at these cases and maybe one or two more, do you have a suspicion for what a more general answer might possibly be?

Comment: In the first case the fundamental period is 6 and in the second 4. Ok, so I can visualize that is gcf.

Comment: But that always the fundamental period?

Comment: I think you mean lcm rather than gcf. And yes, that turns out to be the general answer. All that's left is to reason why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$e^{ik_{1}x}+e^{ik_{2}x} = \cos(k_{1}x)+\cos(k_{2}x) + i[\sin(k_{1}x)+\sin(k_{2}x)] = 2\cos\bigg{[}\frac{(k_{1}+k_{2})x}{2}\bigg{]}\cos\bigg{[}\frac{(k_{1}-k_{2})x}{2}\bigg{]}+2i \sin\bigg{[}\frac{(k_{1}+k_{2})x}{2}\bigg{]}\cos\bigg{[}\frac{(k_{1}-k_{2})x}{2}\bigg{]} = 2\cos\bigg{[}\frac{(k_{1}-k_{2})x}{2}\bigg{]}e^{i\frac{(k_{1}+k_{2})x}{2}}$$
Now, let $T_{1} = \frac{4\pi}{k_{1}-k_{2}}$, the period of $\cos\frac{(k_{1}-k_{2})x}{2}$, (assuming $k_{1} \neq k_{2}$) and $T_{2} = \frac{4\pi}{k_{1}+k_{2}}$ the period of $e^{i\frac{(k_{1}+k_{2})x}{2}}$. Suppose $\frac{T_{1}}{T_{2}}$ is rational, that is:
$$\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{k_{1}-k_{2}} = \frac{n}{n}$$
for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, take $T = T_{1}m$. We have:
$$\frac{k_{1}-k_{2}}{2}T_{1}m = \frac{k_{1}-k_{2}}{2}\frac{4\pi}{k_{1}-k_{2}}m = 2\pi m$$ 
and
$$\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{2}T_{1}m = \frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{2}\frac{4\pi}{k_{1}-k_{2}}m = 2\pi  m\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{k_{1}-k_{2}} = 2\pi m \frac{n}{m} = 2\pi n $$
Thus, $T$ is a period for $e^{i k_{1}x}+e^{ik_{2}x}$.